# How to cCythonize a C++ function that accepts a container as input for returning result

Tags: python, cython

I'm learning Cython to expose C++ classes to Python. I'm successful in exposing simple C++ classes without many issues. However, I have the following problem:

I have a function with the following C++ signature:

```
void foo(std::vector<bool>&result, std::vector<int> const& x, std::vector<int> const& y)
```

Note that I can't change the function signature as this is a third-party library.

How do I write the appropriate Cython code to export this? The problem is the 'result' container which is passed to foo() to return the result. Any (small) example on how to do this would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Updated:

Following Czarek's solution, I got it to work this way:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp cimport bool as cpp_bool

cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":  
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        ....
        void foo(vector[cpp_bool]& result, vector[int] x, vector[int] y)

cdef class PyRectangle:
    def foo(self, x, y):
        cdef vector[cpp_bool] tmp_result
        self.thisptr.foo(tmp_result, x, y)


        result = []
        for i in tmp_result:
          result.append(i)
        return result
```

Let me know if there is a better way to convert the vector to a python list (object). Thanks!

Comment: Found these two examples on github.com/cython/cython by searching "vector": 1) [libcpp_all.pyx#L89](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/0c62e665c02b438be331e445bbde2f1c6bd9dff0/tests/run/libcpp_all.pyx#L89) 2) [memview_vector.pyx#L11](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/b476c360bff59f8fa868ffd03f107ac1664e4a6f/tests/run/memview_vector.pyx#L11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp cimport bool as cpp_bool

cdef extern from ...:
    cdef void foo(vector[cpp_bool]& result, ...)
```